# What is the meaning of a type hint within the top level of a class?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am trying to understand the syntax of a class in PyTorch named [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/2de327cedc889653f42775f16400bec9119dc5c0/torch/nn/modules/loss.py#L1043). The part that I am concerned about, looks like this:

```
class CrossEntropyLoss(_WeightedLoss):
    __constants__ = ['ignore_index', 'reduction', 'label_smoothing']
    ignore_index: int
    label_smoothing: float

    def __init__(self, weight: Optional[Tensor] = None, size_average=None, ignore_index: int = -100,
                 reduce=None, reduction: str = 'mean', label_smoothing: float = 0.0) -> None:
        super().__init__(weight, size_average, reduce, reduction)
        self.ignore_index = ignore_index
        self.label_smoothing = label_smoothing

[...]
```

I am unable to figure out what the meaning of the third, `ignore_index: int`, and fourth, `label_smoothing: float`, lines is.

They look like type hints for `ignore_index` and `label_smoothing`, but this information seems redundantly given in the `__init__` function.

On top of this duplication, the following class uses different types in both places and does not give any error in `mypy`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


class A:
    num: float

    def __init__(self, num: int = 5):
        self.num = num


a = A()
print("type(a.num) = " + str(type(a.num)))

# both lines give
## AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'num'
print("type(A.num) = " + str(type(A.num)))
print("A.num = " + str(A.num))
```

Executing it with Python 3.12 gives:

```
$ ./static_var_test.py 
type(a.num) = <class 'int'>    <--------------------- NOTE: not float
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./static_var_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("type(A.num) = " + str(type(A.num)))
                                      ^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'num'
```

Output of `mypy`:

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 1.8.0 (compiled: yes)
$ mypy static_var_test.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

How are type hints within the top level of a class useful?

Comment: `__init__` arguments and instance attributes are separate things, that need separate type information.

Comment: Talking about my class `A`, I don't think `num` is an instance attribute. To be a instance attribute, it would have to be initialized, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some prelude on the different cases: default vs. not-set and instance vs. class.

While not necessary to define type hints annotations it is to distinguish these cases use-cases, see [PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations).

First you can declare variables explicitly with a value(which do not necessarily need to be type hinted.)
However, there is the question do you want an attribute for the whole *class* to be shared across all instances (`ClassName.shared`) or do you want a default value for each *instance* (`Apple("Big").price`).

The official example is a ship, each ship of the same class should have the same stats.
Each instance however can have their own captain, but you want to declare a default **and maybe change/access it**, accessing default arguments from functions is not very clean.
As instance-default and class-default are shared there is the `ClassVar` type hint to distinguish those cases.

```
class BasicStarship:
    captain: str = 'AI'               # instance variable with default
    damage: int                           # instance variable without default
    stats: ClassVar[Dict[str, int]] = {}  # class variable


  def __init__(self, damage: int, captain: str = None):
        self.damage = damage
        if captain:
            self.captain = captain  # Else keep the default
```

---

> How are type hints within the top level of a class useful?

- One argument is you can more easily keep track of default-instance values you want to implement.
  If you have some inheritance hierarchy with custom init functions you maybe are not 100% sure if all classes implement all defaults.
  This makes it more similar to C or Java where you have this overview as well; **TL;DR and my opinion cleaner programming**.
- They are not redundant with the arguments for init.
  The latter might be more comprehensive, e.g. if multiple types are allowed, and some preprocessing is done before the final value

```
class Coin:
    values : List[int]

    def __init__(self, values : Union[List[int], int]):
        # fix single values entries
        if not isisntance(Iterable, values):
           self.values = [values] # correct type from 2 allowed.
```

---

Furthermore, annotations align brilliantly with [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html)